# How can I can get the new record ID after saving data with JModel?

Tags: development, mvc, jmodel

We need to create a new usergroup for the installation of our component, and the below code *saves* the data just as expected.  However, retrieving the ID of the Usergroup for later use "isn't working".

Using JTable returns the ID, but won't fire any plugins - am I missing something obvious here in retrieving the ID of the record that the model just added?

```
$model = new UsersModelGroup(array('table_path' => $basePath.'/tables'));
$data = array('parent_id' => '2','title'=>'My Usergroup');
if(!$model->save($data)){
    $msg = 'Usergroup was not saved: '.$model->getError();
}else{
    $my_new_group_id = $model->get('id');    // Returns "null"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the `postSaveHook` method which allows the controller to access model data after it has been saved.

```
public function postSaveHook($model, $validData)
{
    $item = $model->getItem();
    $my_new_group_id = $item->get('id');
}
```

Comment: Drat - foiled again by the getItem() method....glad I mentioned that I knew it was going to be obvious, lol.

Comment: Glad it helped :) Do I get flowers this time: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/4255/168 ? lol

Comment: I was hoping you'd forgotten that....i looked at the price of shipping to where you're at.

Comment: The trick is to call a local flower place and have them deliver it. Much cheaper that way ;)

Answer (score 2):

Even though this is an old post. I wanted to post one of the solutions that helped me.

```
JLoader::import('group', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_users/models');
$groupModel = JModelLegacy::getInstance( 'Group', 'UsersModel' );
$groupModel->save($group);
$groupId = $groupModel->getState('group.id');
```